# inline assembly Visual c++ get value from a pointer

Tags: c++, assembly

I have a question yesterday I made a test to get value from a pointer like this is it correct?. It seems that it works fine.

```
    char *test ="abcdef";
_asm{
         mov ebx, test
         mov al, byte ptr ds:[ebx]; element at 0
         mov al, byte ptr ds:[ebx + 1]; element at 1...
         mov al, byte ptr ds:[ebx + x]; element at x...
     }
```

Comment: Following the instructions for code formatting works a lot better than `<code>` and `<br>` tags: Indent each line with 4 spaces, or highlight the block and click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Now Does it look better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. A pointer is just an address, and you're using an indirect addressing mode through `ebx` to access what the pointer points to.

Comment: I used ollydbg to see how compiler address a pointer and i copied it, but i have a doubt is it correct use ebx, ecx... to access memory or should I use ebp.

Comment: @Luis - It is fine to use ebx to hold a pointer. In some functions ebp might be used to point at the local stack frame, so you should be more careful with that. If you look at old 16-bit code, we had different data segments at that time and it was important that bx was associated with the ds segment and bp with the ss segment. Not so anymore.

Comment: Ok thanks it's true epb is associated by compiler for arguments in stack